# Are boolean reads and writes guaranteed atomic in swift?

Tags: swift, x86, arm, atomic

Lets say I have an application that is writing to a boolean from one thread and reading from the same boolean from another thread.

I don't care if my reading thread reads a stale value. Is this safe on all ARM cores and x86? I don't want to run into an issue were a partially written value is read by my reading thread.

Follow up question: Which swift types have guaranteed atomic reads and writes on x86 and ARM?

Comment: On x86, [naturally-aligned loads/stores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic/36685056) of up to 64bits are atomic.  So unless Swift does something perverse (like use an unaligned 32bit value), then yes, they're atomic.  For a boolean, "tearing" probably doesn't even matter, because the upper bits of true and false are both zero.  (Unless Swift stores booleans as 0 / -1 (all-ones)?)

Comment: And the same is true for ARM (note, there are 64-bit and 32-bit ARM cores). I do not think Swift or any other language has anything to do with this, it's all down to CPU load/store instructions.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev It's absolutely to do with Swift, because it's a question of which of those underlying machine types the language ABI chooses to implement the higher-level types with.

Comment: @Notlikethat I'll shut up, then, as I know nothing about Swift. :)

Comment: @FreaknBigPanda don't rely on this, it seems fragile and poorly designed. Stick to established multi-threading the IPC techniques.

Comment: Does Apple really not talk about Swift variable atomicity anywhere? They do for ObjC, which has that `atomic` keyword. All I can find on Swift is the low-level APIs.